# No option for keeping installed programs when upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, windows-8

(Related : [How can I upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and keep my files and applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/463409/how-can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-8-and-keep-my-files-and-applications) )

I'm trying to upgrade my Windows 7 Pro (msdnaa) to Windows 8 Pro (msdnaa).

The Windows 8 is the final version (I don't have access to previews on msdnaa anymore).

As you can see on the related question accepted answer, Windows 8 should give an option to keep installed programs. But it does not. The only available options are "Keep only personal datas" and "Nothing".

Any idea ?

I'm running with SP1. I've got two partitions (one of them only contains data of a virtual machine).
The two operating systems have the same architecture (64 bits).

Screenshot, except that I don't see the "Keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps" option :

[image: screenshot from www.7tutorials.com/files/img/upgrade_win8/upg1.png]

Comment: Are they the same architecture (32, and/or 64 bit)?

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, it seems that upgrade shouldn't be possible at all if the two architectures were different.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was getting at.  Maybe edit that info into your question.  Also perhaps include partition and drive types (dynamic, basic, GPT, NTFS, software RAID, etc.), service pack levels, etc.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to upgrade Windows 7 x86 to Windows 8 x64 cause that isn't possible.  Furthermore if you don't have access to MSDNAA anymore how do you have a copy from MSDNAA ( its actually called Dreamspark Pro ).

Comment: No, I'm upgrading from x64 -> x64. And I have access to the MSDNAA. But the Consumer Previews are not in my interface anymore (so I can't have downloaded the CP instead of the RTM)

Comment: Sounds like setup detects the OS as XP instead of 7

Comment: @NisonMaël Can you show us a screen print of what you see?

Comment: I have made a fresh install, but it was like [this screen](http://www.7tutorials.com/files/img/upgrade_win8/upg1.png), except that there wasn't the first option.

Comment: Maybe youre trying to install a crossed language version.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design.  Windows is not being upgraded, but being replaced with the new version.  The registry is not being imported, nor are older applications.

Comment: You are normally able to upgrade Windows 7 Pro to 8 Pro.  I'm pretty sure the OP is asking why he can't.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do an upgrade, not a reinstallation (upgrades are done when the OS is booted, reinstallation are using the live cd).

Comment: To my knowledge the licence is upgraded and thats it.  Windows 7 will not be upgraded, but replaced.

Comment: The license is not actually replaced, once Windows is upgraded, the original license depending on some factors ( Retail License vs OEM License ) could actually be also used on another computer.

Comment: @Keltari According to Microsoft you can bring your data, settings, *and* apps along from Win7 only. http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2012/07/02/upgrade-to-windows-8-pro-for-39-99.aspx

Comment: interesting...  dunno... I ran the install from win 7 and was never prompted for this.  granted, it wasnt an official upgrade, but a full release.