# Can I upgrade 32 bit Windows Vista to Windows 8 64 bit?

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and keep my files and applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/463409/how-can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-8-and-keep-my-files-and-applications)

Will the upgrade option for windows 8 allow me to upgrade my 32 bit windows vista ultimate to 64 bit version of windows 8?

Comment: architecture upgrades are never possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cross architecture upgrades are not possible - it wasn't so with Windows 7, and the same with Windows 8.

[Mary Jo Foley mentions:](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-details-its-windows-8-upgrade-plans/13051)

> Users will be able to upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows Vista (without SP1 installed) but only personal files (meaning data only) will be maintained. If upgrading from Vista with SP1, personal data and system settings will be maintained.
>
> Microsoft also is not allowing users interested in doing a
> cross-architecture -- i.e., 32-bit to 64-bit -- install to do so.
> Whether running Vista or Windows 7, these users won't be able to keep
> their existing Windows settings, personal files, and applications or
> data. They won't be allowed to upgrade this way, period.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't upgrade from 32-bit Vista to Win 8 64-bit. Here's the info from ZDNet:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-details-its-windows-8-upgrade-plans/13051

Quote: "Microsoft also is also not allowing users interested in doing a cross-architecture -- i.e., 32-bit to 64-bit -- install to do so. Whether running Vista or Windows 7, these users won't be able to keep their existing Windows settings, personal files and applications or data. They won't be allowed to upgrade this way, period."