# Upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-update

My PC is running a bit slow lately, and I want to format it. I have a Windows 8 upgrade disc (upgrades from Windows 7 to Windows 8).

I've seen here :
[How can I upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 and keep my files and applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/463409/how-can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-8-and-keep-my-files-and-applications)

That it asks you in the upgrade what to keep

If I will click "Nothing", will it format my entire C hard drive ?
Because maybe I can just upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 8 and it'll automatically format it, instead of re-installing Windows 7, and then upgrading to windows 8.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to speed up your PC, then you should consider reformatting it. Upgrading will just update components of your current, slow system, resulting in an upgraded, but still slow system. You should perform a clean install and then restore files and programs by hand.

Comment: I've noticed that if I boot the CD from the boot, I get the option to run a clean Windows 8 installation, and format my C and D drives... just like in a normal Win7 installation, though this is a Win8 upgrade CD...
So I guess if I'll choose in the boot installation (Custome - Advanced) instead of Modify, it'll run a full setup of win8 ?