# How can I make Windows 8 let me keep my files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I am trying to upgrade to Windows 8 (and yes, it is a legit copy), but it isn't giving me the option to keep my files...

I am currently running Windows 7 Ultimate and trying to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro.  Is there a reason that the only option for keeping my files is "none"?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The only reason for this behavior if you were trying to install a 64-bit Windows 8 installation and have a 32-bit installation of Windows 7 installed.  Its also possible you have a System Builder ( OEM ) license instead of the Windows 8 Professional Upgrade license.  Its also possible your trying to simply upgrade to Windows 8 Core.  All of these are well documented.  Provider more information which isn't covered by the following question's answer http://superuser.com/questions/463409/how-can-i-upgrade-from-windows-7-to-windows-8-and-keep-my-files-and-applications?rq=1

Comment: I am defintely using the x64 Windows 7... I have 32GB of RAM.  I am using OEM windows though because I built my own laptop.  Why is that a problem?  And if I do upgrade and not keep anything, will I still have my files in a "windows.old" folder?

Comment: `Do Nothing` will keep nothing.  Your personal files will be deleted.  You are using a the Upgrade Assistant Tool correct?  You having a Windows 7 OEM license has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: I am still really confused as to where my problem is.  I don't think the other question you linked to helps me at all.  But please let me know if I am wrong.  I am just using the "Windows 8 Setup" that came with the download.  I am using a copy that my school provided.

Comment: The chart explains your using the Windows 8 Core instead of Windows 8 Professional Setup.  Did you use the upgrade assistant to download the Setup.exe?  What version of Windows 8 did you purchase?

Comment: As a work around - shrink your partition then create a new partition and move your personal files to that. Post installation copy em back over and restore your original partition configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound I downloaded Windows 8 for free though a service my school provides.  I updated the post with a screenshot of where I downloaded it from.

Comment: It says Upgrade but I suspect its the System Builder edition ask your IT Administrator for assistance.